# How to automatically parse csv in python 2.7 into int, string and list objects and their values

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I want to be able to parse csv files that will be maintained outside of our software group. A sample csv may contain:

```
temperature,50,55,56
color,blue
count,10
dummy,line
```

The code will search the file for a list of ints called temperature, a string called color and an int called count. Then it will assign the values [50, 55, 56], 'blue' and 10 respectively.

- The row ordering in the csv files is arbitrary (e.g. sometimes 'color' could come before 'temperature').
- The object names are predefined but the values will vary between csv files.
- The csv files will always contain the object names that the python code searches for.
- The csv files may contain extra data rows that are not useful to the python code.
- The object names will always be in the first column of the csv.

I have seen other code examples that search for specific object types, or objects in predefined row positions. However, I need a solution that is more robust.

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if you need clarification and I will edit.

Comment: What did you try before post this question ?

Comment: @Zulu I tried something similar to Michael's below but without first initializing the object names and not knowing how to return a list who's size would vary before csv files. So yes, it was lengthy and messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is something like the following:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    dummy = []
    temperature = []
    color = ''
    count = 0

    for row in reader:
        try:
            if row[0] == 'temperature':
                temperature = map(int, row[1:])
            elif row[0] == 'color':
                color = row[1]
            elif row[0] == 'count':
                count = int(row[1])
            else:
                dummy.append(row)

        # for robustness, let's catch the case where a row
        # may be malformed or does not contain more than 1 column
        except IndexError:
            dummy.append(row)
```